# SQL Insert suspended due to pagelatch_ex

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a MS SQL 2008 database with a few thousand records. Suddenly one of the table cannot accept new row insert. Edit and delete are still okay. In Activity Monitor, it shows as:

Task State: Suspended
Command: Insert
Wait Type: Pagelatch_ex

Nothing happens after a few minutes of waiting. If I delete one of the latest (bottom) 200 (estimate) rows in that table, I can insert one new row only. Inserting second row is suspended again. If I delete 3 rows among the latest 200 rows, I can only insert 3 new rows. But if I delete row not within the latest 200, I cannot insert any row.

After inserting new row, new ID goes to the top in SSMS results view, instead of bottom (without sorting). Eg: 100, 101, 102, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99 where 100 and above are newly inserted data.

Now the table only have 2 columns, ID (Primary column, identity seed) and InvoiceID column. All indexed views, tables and constraints are removed, with the same problem.

I just found out that removing the primary key for ID column and set it back again solves the problem. However, the sorting for ID still get messed up. New row get positioned on upper part and old rows are pushed down.

What causes this problem and how to prevent it? Thanks.

Comment: You might get more insight if you post this problem at https://dba.stackexchange.com/. This is a Stackoverflow-related site specifically for database administration questions.

Answer (score 0):

Pagelatch_ex occurs when there is a request for a page that needs to be modified. Typically, the latch is short lived & doesn't affect performance. However, you can hit issues if you have slow I/O subsystem or other resource bottlenecks. You need to first identify which database/table is involved & go from there.

Start with the [troubleshooting performance problems whitepaper](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672789(v=sql.100).aspx). It describes steps for troubleshooting various performance issues - how to use DMVs, performance counters and so on.